# SQL Delete vs Update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have seen something like this asked a number of times but not quite in this configuration.  I have a table that has a one to many relation.

Let’s say I have a computer table and a parts table.  The user enters a generic info in the computer table then selects parts that are stored in the parts table with a relationship to the computer table of computerId.  So the original write is a simple insert.  Now let’s say the user select the computer again and changes the part on the pc, adds some new, removes some, and updates a few.  Then the user hits save to save the changes.  I run a simple update on the computer table but now the issue with the parts table.

Would it be better to delete all the records from the parts table for the computer Id  and then do a clean insert of all the parts selected.
Or Run some method that would look at the existing parts in the table and where the part has been updated update the record, where the part no longer exists do a delete, and then insert the remaining parts?

Comment: I think the standard process would be to update the computer separately from each part and update the parts one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the simple solution is to delete all and then insert all.
The down side of this SQL traffic, locks, and table fragmentation.
If it is small table and only few concurrent users then fine.

In a high volume environment I do the following
There is no update - that is just an ignore
-  delete items gone
-  ignore any items not changed
-  insert new items
And you can do that in one pass two/three statements.
Or you could define a stored procedure.
Do the delete before the insert to clear space first.

You can get real fancy and use an update for delete / insert but that just gets more complex than it is worth in my mind.  You would still have an insert or a delete if the item count is not the same.

```
delete comp_part 
 where compID = @compID and partID not in (....);
```

Insert is a little more tricky:
You can to it with a series of inserts and if you have a PK just let the insert fail
The other way is to create a @table and use it for both the delete and insert

This is only worth the hassle if you have a REALLY busy table.

Comment: The big issue I was trying to figure out is if records are add, changed, and removed was the performance.  I delete proc to first delete all records of the child table and then insert new records would it be faster or would getting all the existing records from sql them looping through them, run a comparison to determine what action to take and then take the appropriate action seems like it would take longer.

Comment: You do it with a join or a an exists.  I will post a simple.

Comment: sorry hit that post by accident.  It has been corrected

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the business model, if you would want to track the transaction than its not a good option to delete it. If you have all your old transactions with your customers than it would be beneficial for tracking purposes., Your CustomerID would be Primarykey and you can have another Unique key as PartOrderID which will be a unique value for each insert.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Really you should have three tables. Product, Part, and ProductPart; the ProductPart table would store the association of "this product has these parts". As far as updating, the simplest thing would be to delete all ProductParts for a given Product and re-insert the records you want.